# Why is Java RMI server showing an error message when I try to run it?

Tags: java, rmi

The following exception is thrown after the execution of the program.

> Unresolved compilation problem:   The method bind(String, Remote) in
>   the type Registry is not applicable for the arguments (String,
>   EmployeeRMIMain)

```
    public static void main(String args[]){
        try {
            EmployeeRMIMain obj = new EmployeeRMIMain();
            Registry r = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(1234);
            r.bind("Remote", obj);
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (AlreadyBoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I figured out the problem.

Comment: No. The following *error message* is *printed*, and this is *instead of* the execution of the program.

Comment: Don't edit your question to remove the problem that you are asking about. Makes it usesless for other readers: also self-contradictory as the corrected code cannot possibly cause the error message shown. Or else delete your question.

Answer (score 0):

edit: User already solved his own problem. @KMuir it is a good practice to post a solution even if you found it.

What is the class interfaces of EmployeeService class? Are you sure it implements Remote marker interface?

```
public interface TunnelingMessageBox extends Remote {
  public void pushMessage(Message message) throws RemoteException;
  //..more interface methods
}

public class TunnelingMessageBoxImpl implements TunnelingMessageBox {
  public void pushMessage(Message message) throws RemoteException {
     // does the magic
  }
}

public class MyService {
  private Registry registry;
  private int port;
  public void createRegistry(int port) throws RemoteException {
        Registry reg;
        try {
            reg = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(port);
        } catch (ExportException ex) {
            // get existing registry instance.
            reg = LocateRegistry.getRegistry(port);
        }
        this.port=port;
        registry = reg;
  }

  public vooid closeRegistry() {
    try {
      Remote obj = (Remote)registry.lookup("box1");
      UnicastRemoteObject.unexportObject(obj, true);
      registry.unbind("box1");
    } catch(Exception ex) { ex.printStacktrace(); }
    registry=null;
  }

  public void registerServices() throws RemoteException {
    TunnelingMessageBoxImpl mbox = new TunnelingMessageBoxImpl();
    UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(mbox, port);
    registry.rebind("box1", mbox);
  }

}
```

Comment: I had made to corrections to the code that I posted initially. The problem was that I was creating an object of the wrong class. I was creating an object of this class (EmployeeRMIMain) instead of the updated EmployeeService Class in the above code. The error occurred because the EmployeeRMIMain Method does not inheriting from the following class UnicastRemoteObject.

Answer (score 0):

I had made to corrections to the code that I posted initially. The problem was that I was creating an object of the wrong class.

I was creating an object of this class (EmployeeRMIMain) instead of the updated EmployeeService Class in the above code. The error occurred because the EmployeeRMIMain Method does not inheriting from the following class UnicastRemoteObject.